# How can I round the corners of a button in c#?

Tags: c#, button

I need to round the corners of existing buttons, without crating a new round corner buttons in my windows form application. How can I do this.I could only find new creation of button codes from the internet.

Comment: Do you want that for winforms, wpf, xamarin, uwp or web? You can [edit] your question to add the appropriate tag so you get answer(s) that fit your context.

Comment: Based on your lack of success so far this must be a WinForms question. You may have some success with handling the `Paint` event, but seriously you should just create a new button control like the examples you have already found. Why is it that you can't do that?

Answer (score 0):

Salvaging an older post you can write this simple function to apply rounding to an existing `Button` or other control..:

```
void makeRound(Control ctl, int radius)
{
    ctl.Paint += (s, e) =>
    {
        RectangleF Rect = new RectangleF(0, 0, ctl.Width, ctl.Height);
        GraphicsPath GraphPath = GetRoundPath(Rect, 20);

        ctl.Region = new Region(GraphPath);
        using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.CadetBlue, 1.75f))
        {
            pen.Alignment = PenAlignment.Inset;
            e.Graphics.DrawPath(pen, GraphPath);
        }
    };
}

GraphicsPath GetRoundPath(RectangleF Rect, int radius)
{
    float r2 = radius / 2f;
    GraphicsPath GraphPath = new GraphicsPath();

    GraphPath.AddArc(Rect.X, Rect.Y, radius, radius, 180, 90);
    GraphPath.AddLine(Rect.X + r2, Rect.Y, Rect.Width - r2, Rect.Y);
    GraphPath.AddArc(Rect.X + Rect.Width - radius, Rect.Y, radius, radius, 270, 90);
    GraphPath.AddLine(Rect.Width, Rect.Y + r2, Rect.Width, Rect.Height - r2);
    GraphPath.AddArc(Rect.X + Rect.Width - radius, 
                    Rect.Y + Rect.Height - radius, radius, radius, 0, 90);
    GraphPath.AddLine(Rect.Width - r2, Rect.Height, Rect.X + r2, Rect.Height);
    GraphPath.AddArc(Rect.X, Rect.Y + Rect.Height - radius, radius, radius, 90, 90);
    GraphPath.AddLine(Rect.X, Rect.Height - r2, Rect.X, Rect.Y + r2);

    GraphPath.CloseFigure();
    return GraphPath;
}
```

`Region` will not allow antialiasing so it looks a bit rough around the rounded edges.